# Function for formatting and plotting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to create a function that will format my data and properly and return a bar plot that is sorted. Yet for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Var1", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3
```

I have tried debugging it, but have had no luck. I have an example of what I expect down at the bottom. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
x <- rep(c("Mark","Jimmy","Jones","Jones","Jones","Jimmy"),2)
y <- rnorm(12)
df <- data.frame(x,y)


plottingfunction <- function(data, name,xlabel,ylabel,header){
  newDf <- data.frame(table(data))
  order <- newDf[order(newDf$Freq, decreasing = FALSE), ]$Var1
  newDf$Var1 <- factor(newDf$Var1,order)
  colnames(newDf)[1] <- name

  plot <- ggplot(newDf, aes(x=name, y=Freq)) +
                xlab(xlabel) +
                ylab(ylabel) +
                ggtitle(header) +
                geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightblue", colour="black") +
                coord_flip()
  return(plot)

}

plottingfunction(df$x, "names","xlabel","ylabel","header")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments, your function didn't work, because this part isn't correct:

```
order <- newDf[order(newDf$Freq, decreasing = FALSE), ]$Var1
```

Since we have no idea if there will be any columns in `data` which has the column name `Var1`. What looks like happend is when you were trying your code you ran:

```
newDf <- data.frame(table(df$x))
```

which immediately renamed your column to `Var1`, but when you ran your function, the name changed. So to get around this I would recommend being explicit with your column names. In this example, I used the `dplyr` library to make my life easier. So following your code and logic it would look like this:

```
newDf <- data %>% group_by_(col_name) %>% tally
order <- newDf[order(newDf$n, decreasing = FALSE), col_name][[col_name]]
data[,col_name] <- factor(data[,col_name], order)
```

Then within your `ggplot` we can use `aes_string` to refer to the column name of the data frame instead. So then the whole function would look like this:

```
plottingFunction <- function(data, col_name, xlabel, ylabel, header) {
  #' create a dataframe with the data that we're interested in 
  #' make sure that you preserve the anme of the column that you're
  #' counting on...
    newDf <- data %>% group_by_(col_name) %>% tally
    order <- newDf[order(newDf$n, decreasing = FALSE), col_name][[col_name]]
    data[,col_name] <- factor(data[,col_name], order)

  plot <- ggplot(data, aes_string(col_name)) +
    xlab(xlabel) +
    ylab(ylabel) +
    ggtitle(header) +
    geom_bar(fill="lightblue", colour="black") +
    coord_flip()
  return(plot)
}

plottingFunction(df, "x", "xlabel","ylabel","header")
```

Which would have output like:

[image]

I think for your plot having `stat="identity"` is redundant since you can just use your original data frame rather than having a transformed one.